# CORS error when trying to request access_token from oauth/token endpoint Auth0

Tags: next.js, oauth, cors, auth0

After i authorize my user with the '/authorize' endpoint i need the user to get an access_token to access my API. I am currently trying to do this in Next.js by making a post request to the 'oauth/token' endpoint with all the required parameters.

Example code of the request in Next.js:

```
let tokenParams = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: process.env.client_id,
    client_secret: process.env.client_secret,
    code: router.query.code,
    redirect_uri: process.env.base_url
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://neume.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }, tokenParams)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }, [])
```

However, this request returns a CORS error everytime.

I tried setting the Allowed Origins in the application settings in Auth0 to 'http://localhost:3000' but this does not seem to work. When i make this request in Postman it works perfectly. I feel like i am doing everything right but i have no idea why it is not working.

I hope someone can tell me what is going on here and provide me with a possible solution.

Comment: Share the entire error. It may also help to see the CORS headers returned by the server for the failing request.

Comment: Lastly it's highly suspicious to see a `client_secret` in react code.

Answer (score 3):

The request you are trying to make is an OpenID Connect [token request](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest), which must be made by your *server* to the OAuth authorization server, not by the browser (that is, not by your React *frontend*). Only your server should have the `client_secret`, it should not be exposed to your frontend.

Since the authorization server expects token requests to be made by a server, not a browser, it makes sense that it does not allow CORS for the token endpoint.

[This documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/oidc-conformant-authentication/oidc-adoption-auth-code-flow#code-exchange-request-authorization-code-flow) describes how to make the token request (they call it a "code exchange request") in various server-side programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` (and `XMLHttpRequest`) are same-origin (on the server), that is the request file needs to be on the same server as the `.htm` file.

> The [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method is controlled by the `connect-src` directive of [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) rather than the directive of the resources it's retrieving.

The [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol) deals with this. A 'cross-server' can allow its responses to be loaded by specifying this in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - the client browser can't.

So instead, `fetch` a file written in your server-side language, and access the URL from there, using [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) for example. You then return the response to the AJAX call, and you are done.

In [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), an example is

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$pBody);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
echo $result;
```

where `$pBody` contains the `tokenParams` data in `POST` query format.