# Unable to enable CORS in WordPress for JWT authentication?

Tags: jwt, cors, wordpress-rest-api

I have tried to enable CORS on my WordPress application as a REST API by following guidance provided by different sources, but I'm still facing CORS problems. The OPTIONS request to the route '/json/jwt-auth/v1/token' is still being blocked by the browser with the error 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:10016/json/jwt-auth/v1/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy'. My environment is as follows:

Local By Flywheel

Web server: nginx
PHP version: 8.1.9
Database: MySQL 8.0.16
WordPress version: 6.2

I have tried the following approaches:
Adding CORS response headers in the nginx server configuration file
Using the "Enable CORS" plugin for WordPress
Using the "WP CORS Everywhere" plugin for WordPress
Nothing seems to be working. Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?"

---

This is my ".htaccess" file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Making token requests as CORS requests seems not right, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75904665/16462950).